# How to run TestNG suite from command line

Tags: selenium, command-line, webdriver, testng

I would like to run `TestNG Suite` from command line on `Linux`. I'm using `eclipse` to run test, but I have problem with command line. I know that I need to have `testng.jar` and I have it in `/home/karcio/dev/testng-6.4.jar`, location my suite xml is `/home/karcio/git/java-test-automation/Automation/test-output/Default suite/TestSuite.xml` . Commands what I tried,

1. set classpath `/home/karcio/dev/testng-6.4.jar`
2. cd /location to my suite xml file: `java org.testing.TestNG TestSuite.xml`

This is error what I see:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testing/TestNG
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testing.TestNG`

I'm new in those path and classpath, I'm little bit confusing :(

Thank you

Little update, 
I think I did all good, now when I put to terminal: `java org.testng.TestNG Test.xml` 
I've got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException:  No sourcedir
>   was specified     at org.testng.TestNG.checkConditions(TestNG.java:1170)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1010)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:997)

all path are exported, so maybe this is wrong version of `testng.jar`, tried with versions `5.5`, `6.4`, `6.5`, `6.6`, `6.7` but I think only version `5.5` is working,

Comment: Are you compiling your java classes first? I'd suggest looking into using Ant to compile and run your suite.

Comment: Yes. I also exported CLASSPATH for my class files (/bin/*class). I read that "No sourcedir was specified" I should remove java doc but I did not create any :(

Comment: There is typing mistake in your command. It should be testng instead of testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in the class package
`org.testing.TestNG`

should be 
`org.testng.TestNG`

(There no i in the .testng. part)

http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestNG.html

Comment: Hi patrungel thx. I did typo but after export classpath I used tab for  AutoComplete, so now I'm free from any mistakes.