# Unable to find testng.xml from executable jar file by using command line [without Maven]

Tags: java, xml, selenium, cmd, testng

I have used TestNG in my Selenium project & developed, Run testcases from eclipse as testng project. It works fine also invoked TestScript by command line which pointed to Workspace location. But test run is not invoked when exported as executable jar with testng.xml. Here i'm stuck. Can any one guide me with proper approach. [main thing is i need to show this to my TL as POC, by that time need to run test script on his PC, so thought of export as executable jar & will configure with scheduler]

Used the following CMD

> java -cp E:/Softwares/org.testng.eclipse_6.10.0.201612030230/lib/*
>   org.testng.TestNG -testjar TestNGTest.jar -xmlpathinjar testng.xml

Here "testng.xml" is in executable jar TestNGTest.jar

Getting the following error,

> [TestNG] Couldn't find the testng.xml in the jar file, running all the
>   classes [TestNG] [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath:
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JIJConstants

Comment: i have created main class which points to my single test class & able to invoke executable jar file.               public class TestMain {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  TestNG testng = new TestNG();
  testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {CreateProfile.class });
  testng.run();
 }
}                                                                                                            
but not able to invoke with testng.xml                                     
  List<String> suites = new ArrayList<>();
  suites.add("./testng.xml");
  testNG.setTestSuites(suites);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run TestNG suite from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199554/how-to-run-testng-suite-from-command-line)